# Graph connected does not imply $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

Show an example of a function $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} f: \R \times \R\to \R$ such that $f$ is not continuous, but its graph 
$$
\Gamma_f := \left\{\bigl((x, y), f(x, y)\bigr) \mid \text{$(x, y)$ is in the domain of $f$}\right\}
$$ 
is connected (in $\R \times \R \times \R$).

Comment: Any thoughts of your own, or indication of how rigorous an example you're seeking? (Examples suitable for multivariable calculus or for topology may look rather different.)

Comment: See below for my example.  It is a real analysis problem.

Comment: Thanks. :) If you add your example to your question I'll vote to re-open, and will undelete my example, which is has a path-connected graph but is continuous at only one point. (With a small modification based on agha's answer, you can arrange a connected graph for a function that's discontinuous everywhere.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Choose a function such that the overall limit at $(0,0)$ does not exist (but the limit along some path does).

**Example:** take
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
0 & x = y = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Verify that $\Gamma_f$ is path-connected, but $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I did just figure one out:  f(x, y) = (x^2 + y)/(x^2 + y^2) for (x, y) nonzero and = 0 at (0, 0).  The graph is path-connected (easy to see, since f is continuous outside of the origin), but f certainly isn't continuous at the origin itself.  (The limit as (x, y) goes to (0, 0) doesn't even exist along the y-axis.)

Comment: It's not clear to me that $((0,0),0)$ is path connected to any other part of the graph.  In fact, I don't think it is.

Comment: Actually, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

$$f(x,y)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

and $f(0,0)=0$

Then graph of this function is:

$$\{(x,y,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right))|(x,y) \neq (0,0)\} \cup \{(0,0,0)\}$$

Closure of this graph is:

$$\{(x,y,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right))|(x,y) \neq (0,0)\} \cup \{(0,0,x): x \in [-1,1]\}$$

There is a theorem that if closure of set is connected then set is connected. You can check by definition that closure is connected.

Comment: Your example seems correct, but the final assertion (a set with connected closure is connected) looks suspicious, e.g., $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$...? (The converse is true: The closure of a connected set is connected.)

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} & \text{if $x \neq 0$ and $y/x$ is rational,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

**Theorem**: The function $f$ has (path-)connected graph, but is continuous at precisely one point.

*Proof*: The graph of $f$ is the union of:

- Lines (through the origin) of irrational slope in the $(x, y)$-plane;
- The $y$-axis;
- Absolute value graphs over lines (through the origin) of rational slope in the $(x, y)$-plane.

Since each of these sets is (path-)connected and contains the origin, their union is (path-)connected.

Since lines (through the origin) of irrational slope are dense in the plane, $f$ is continuous at $(x, y)$ if and only if $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} = 0$, if and only if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.