# Connected graph of real function, but function not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am reading Strichartz' The Way of Analysis. He mentions in the beginning of chapter on contionuous functions that

> "Now it is indeed 
>   possible to make a precise mathematical definition of connected sets 
>   in the plane so that the graph of a continuous function is connected. 
>   However, it turns out that there are functions that are not continuous 
>   whose graphs are also connected. "

I cannot imagine any of such graphs. Can I get example of a function, preferably, from $\Bbb R$(or its subset) to $\Bbb R$ such that graph is connected while function is not continuous?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243983/graph-connected-does-not-imply-f-is-continuous

Comment: [Another related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317125/topologists-sine-curve-is-connected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = \sin(\dfrac1x)$ for $x\neq 0$  should work. It's not continuous at $x = 0$ and its graph is connected, I think.